# What are the implications of one site having thousands of links to yours?

Tags: links, pagerank

Using Webmaster I can see the home page of a related site has 100,000 + links to my site. I assume this is because there are tons of pages on this site and a link to our site is in the footer.

My question is how does Google treat this? Surely this must be quite common for huge sites, but does Google see this as suspicious? Do they rank each link or consider the site as a whole and only rank a single link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that suspicious alone.    I own a currency conversion website that commonly gets links on every page of sites that use it to convert prices.

When site-wide links are combined with other spam indicators, then it could become a problem.

- keyword rich anchor text
- hidden text
- on low quality pages among other links that are clearly bought

Comment: Depends on the site to be honest... its actually more natural for sites to have more deeper links than front page links unless they are not natural or in your case a conversion site. In my honest opinion its way more natural and I find best results happen on deeper urls. Far to many businesses and self creating linkers link their top level domain which is why I feel the other way about this.....